# Using Redux with vanilla JS how can I reach it without passing it to every component?

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm using Redux in a vanilla JS project. I have a bunch of small modular UI files and controllers and such. In those UI files I might have code like:

```
const ExampleForm = function (StoreInstance) {
  return $('<form />', {
    submit: () => {
      StoreInstance.dispatch({
        type: 'EXAMPLE_DISPATCH',
        post: {
          message: $TextareaComponent.val()
        }
      })
      return false
    }
  })
}
```

The issue is I have a lot of simple view files like this and many of them are nested and I'm finding it to be ugly and error prone to have the store passed as a param to everything.

For example, I trimmed it for brevity but the form component has form element components such as a textarea. Currently I see two options of managing the Store:

1. Setting it to `window` when creating it in my entry file (index.js) and then just accessing `Store` globally. This seems the nicest, although not "best practice" and makes unit testing and server side rendering a bit harder.
2. Passing it to *every* component tediously. This is my example above. This I'd consider as "best practice" but it's pretty annoying to do for every file you make almost.

I'm wondering if there's any alternatives or tricks to passing the store instance. I'm leaning towards just making it global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the constructor pattern and create every view as `new ConnectedView()`. The ConnectedView would have a memoized instance of the store (`this.store` within the view), so it doesn't need to be global.

Comment: Even though this is an old question, I need your help. Do you mean should I create every UI part by the constructor pattern and make an instance of each piece? I then subscribe each component to the subscribe method of redux. Is it right? Could you please explain more?

Comment: @Behnam Don't know how your code is organized. If we're talking about vanilla js, you do need something that is global in the end - wether it's `window.my_redux_store_instance` or a class `window.ConnectedView` as in my answer above. Once you have a way to access the store instance you can use `subscribe` and `dispatch`, yes.